# Bulk change of Test Case status in Microsoft Test Manager for a particular Test suite

Tags: tfs, testcase, microsoft-test-manager

I'm new to Microsoft Test Manager. I have lot of Test suites in my MTM and want to change the status of each test case from Design to Ready state in a particular test suite.

Is there a way to do it in MTM or TFS without individually changing each and every test case status manually. (There are no tags for the Test Case and I tried to query by test suite name but it doesn't work).

Note:
I know the I could change the state of the test suite to In progress and All the test cases will be available for testing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have latest version of tfs on web test hub you may select several test (screens from vsts):
[image]

set new value for the State field
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query in TFS to find all the test cases that meet your criteria.

Export into Excel (or Import using TEAM tab in Excel) and change all the values and publish the results back.

Or on the latest version of VSTS I can select all the WI's in the Query Result, right click and select "Edit", then change the State to Ready and save all.